# Problems declaring classes and namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

I'm declaring a class like this:

```
#include "BindableInterface.h"
#include "../LuaHelper.h"

#include <map>
#include <string>

namespace utils{
    class CLuaHelper;
};

namespace zel{
    namespace utils{

        class CAPIBindManager
        {
            typedef std::map<std::string, CBindeableInterface*> t_exposedClassMap;
            t_exposedClassMap m_classesToExpose;
            utils::CLuaHelper* m_luaHelper;
        public:
            bool exportClasses(const unsigned char* data);
            bool executeLuaChunk(const std::string fileName, const std::string funtionName);
            bool addClassToExpose(CBindeableInterface* bindableInterface, const std::string alias);
            CAPIBindManager(void);
            ~CAPIBindManager(void);
        };
    };
};
```

But I got a compiling error that CLuaHelper is not a member of zel::utils. CLuaHelper is declared as utils::CLuaHelper (without zel) How do I need to declare this class. AFAIK, the forward declaration might solve this problem

Any ideas??

Comment: try `::utils::CLuaHelper* m_luaHelper;` **::utils** I believe will start look-up from global scope whereas **utils::** will start look up from local scope

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `::utils::CLuaHelper` to distinguish in between the two `utils` namespaces.